# Get true Country with Cloudflare

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

If I call the Link http://freegeoip.net/json/ than it shows my Country correct. But if I call it on my Website by JavaScript than its shows me USA (Cloudflare Server). How can I pass this to show the correct country?

```
<script>
    jQuery.ajax( { 
      url: '//freegeoip.net/json/', 
      type: 'POST', 
      dataType: 'jsonp',
      success: function(location) {
          $("div.country").html(location.country_name);
      }
    });
</script>
<div class="country"></div>
```

Comment: you are running it from server or local enviroment?

Comment: Script is called from Server.. Link is called locally by Browser.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you making the call from your server it get their ip you need to do something like that to get your user ip and sent it to freegeoip

```
<script>    
 function myIP() {
     if (window.XMLHttpRequest) xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
     else xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");

     xmlhttp.open("GET","http://api.hostip.info/get_html.php",false);
     xmlhttp.send();

     hostipInfo = xmlhttp.responseText.split("\n");

     for (i=0; hostipInfo.length >= i; i++) {
       ipAddress = hostipInfo[i].split(":");
       if ( ipAddress[0] == "IP" ) return ipAddress[1];
     }

     return false;
}

var ip  = myIP();

 jQuery.ajax( { 
      url: 'http://freegeoip.net/json/'+ip.replace(' ',''), 
      type: 'POST', 
      dataType: 'jsonp',
      success: function(location) {
          $("div.country").html(location.country_name);
      }
    });

  </script>
  <div class="country"></div>
```

becaus the example above depends to a service `http://api.hostip.info/get_html.php` you could add your own a simply php script to get your user ip address wil be

```
if (!empty($_SERVER['HTTP_CLIENT_IP'])) {
    $ip = $_SERVER['HTTP_CLIENT_IP'];
} elseif (!empty($_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR'])) {
    $ip = $_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR'];
} else {
    $ip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
}
   echo $ip;
```

update again you could get all the info without their ip just with geolocation and reverse geocoding example app

**frontend**

```
<script>   
$( document ).ready(function() {    

if (navigator.geolocation) {
   navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(showPosition);
} 

function showPosition(position) {
    jQuery.ajax( { 
      url: 'geocoder.php', 
      type: 'POST', 
      data:position,
      dataType: 'json',
      success : function(response) {
         $(".country").text(response.address.country);
         $(".postal_code").text(response.address.postcode);
      }

    })
}

})  

</script>
<div class="country"></div>
<div class="postal_code"></div>
```

**geocoder.php**

```
<?php
$lat = $_POST['coords']['latitude'];
$long = $_POST['coords']['longitude'];
$url = "http://nominatim.openstreetmap.org/reverse?format=json&lat=".$lat."&lon=".$long;
$curl_handle=curl_init();
curl_setopt($curl_handle, CURLOPT_URL,$url);
curl_setopt($curl_handle, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 2);
curl_setopt($curl_handle, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($curl_handle, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, 'examples');
$query = curl_exec($curl_handle);
curl_close($curl_handle);
$jsondata = json_decode($query,true);
echo json_encode($jsondata);


?>
```

Comment: that is an example it uses a service from `http://api.hostip.info/get_html.php` i would sugest to make your own service to get your user ip

Comment: Thanks a lot Mat! Is there a way to get more Data like PostalCode, etc?

Comment: you could use some geocode service but your result it wont be 100% accurate like google geocode.give a sec i will add an example

Comment: @karadayi okay i updated my answer with geolocation example it actually return much more data you can look at the response